# Playing RTSP youtube links using wowza server?

Tags: android, video, youtube, rtsp, wowza

I am developing this app where in the video has to be played on the same page without going into the browser mode. I am using wowza server but right now I only can play video files that are present in the server. Is it possible to play rstp youtube links through the WOWZA server?

If i directly play the rtsp videos, they plan perfectly but only on 2g or 3g. The file does not play through WiFi connection.

Comment: Why don't you play the videos directly from youtube ? or use a custom player like jwplayer ? http://www.jwplayer.com/features/